# Is there an easy way to test SSL protected webpages in Development server, using Django?

Tags: django, testing, ssl, security

I use Django for my website and I want to know whether there is a work around for testing secure pages in Development server. As a temporary workaround, I wont use HTTP to check the webpages in dev server, which I think is not a correct way? What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.ianlewis.org/en/testing-https-djangos-development-server) looks helpful -- using stunnel to route HTTPS requests to django dev server.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider `mod_wsgi`, since it can be used for development, testing, and deployment.  `mod_wsgi` can be configured to detect any changes to you make to your Python code and automatically restart, same as the development server.

I tend to do most of my development on my local machine, but use an actual reference implementation server for testing.  It's running mod_wsgi under apache, with a self-signed certificate.  A recent detailed article by **Graham Dumpleton** is available here:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2008/12/using-modwsgi-when-developing-django.html

Comment: what do you mean by "self-signed certificate"??

Answer (score 2):

The Django development server is very basic and intended for local testing only.  It does not support ssl/https.  You'll have to run it using Apache, NGINX, or some other web server that supports SSL in order to test.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use [FakeSSLMiddleware](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/2009/)